# Route all Windows traffic through a vm router (OpenWrt) on VirtualBox

Tags: windows, networking, router, virtualbox, openwrt

I followed the router (OpenWrt)'s wiki guide and successfully got it running and connected to internet. I would like to know how I could route all traffic from my Windows host machine through the router vm (to apply VPN, QoS, smart queue, etc.) before connecting to the internet, as opposed to the Windows host machine going directly to the internet right now.

Comment: what VPN are you using on the router?

Comment: I have not get to the VPN part. Likely VPN Unlimited. Does that matter?